# C menu problem with a validating loop (to many prints)

Tags: c, menu

I'm working on a menu with  a partner (we're collage students) and are unable to solve a bug where some conditions are met the loop prints the menu more times than it needs to.
there is all so the problem i met with when i want to get a negative number into a char variable which i fixed with "(short)input<1" though i think the should be a more memory efficient way to do so.

the code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>


char main() {
    char choice;
    printf("what would you like to do? use number keys to make a choice.\n");
    printf("Database System Menu:\n1. Add person\n2. Search a person\n3. Search Parents\n4. Delete a person\n5. Get generation\n6. Print database\n7. Search by name\n8. Quit\n");
    scanf("%c", &choice);
    while ((short)choice<1 || (short)choice>8) {
        printf("elegal coice use 1 through 8 keys.\n");
        scanf("%c", &choice);
    }
    if ((short)choice >= 1&&(short)choice < 8) {
        return choice;
    }
    else return '\0';
}
```

option 2 that we tried:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
    char input = '0';
    while (input != '8')
    {
        printf("Database System Menu:\n");
        printf("1. Add person\n");
        printf("2. Search a person\n");
        printf("3. Search Parents\n");
        printf("4. Delete a person\n");
        printf("5. Get generation\n");
        printf("6. Print database \n");
        printf("7. Search by name\n");
        printf("8. Quit\n");
        scanf("%c", &input);
        if ((short)input < 1 || input >'8')
        {
            printf("Invalid input\n");

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: `input` can't be `<` of `1` and `>` of `'8'` at the same time, I think that condition is wrong

Comment: typo `&&` -> `||`

Comment: @MarcoBonelli and also `1` -> `'1'`

Comment: Replace `scanf("%c", &input);` with `scanf(" %c", &input);`, mind the space before the `%c` specifier.

Comment: @MarcoLucidi sorry about that that was the least working code we worked on. i have updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%c` specifier as you know gets exactly one character from the standard input, but when you input a character you press <kbd>`Enter`</kbd> causing a newline character to be added to the input buffer, so you'll have two characters in `stdin`, the loop runs twice, the second being caused by that newline character.

---

**Approach #1:**

To discard blank characters such as `\n`, simply use a space before the specifier, ***i.e.*** replace `scanf("%c", &input);` with `scanf(" %c", &input);`, mind the space before the `%c` specifier. The problem that remains is that the loop will cycle as many times as there are characters in the input buffer ***e.g.*** if you input `asdf` the loop will still cycle four times instead of just one.

The negative number question is related to the above, a negative input will need at least 2 characters, so in there lies the problem, the loop will run 3 times for an input of `-9`, 2 times for the 2 characters and a third time for the `\n` (if you haven't fixed the `\n` issue).

---

**Approach #2:** (better)

To discard all characters in stdin you can use something like:

```
int c;
while(( c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){}
```

After the `scanf`.

With this second approach you can solve not only the `\n` problem but also discard any extra characters you input, ***e.g.*** let's say you input `8asds`, the `8` will be parsed but all the other characters will be discarded avoiding unwanted extra loops.

---

Note that a more robust way to do this is to use `fgets` to parse the input string, and if you need to convert it to a numerical value, use `strtoll`, don't use `atoi` it's an unsafe function.

---

`input < 1` looks like it's a typo, you may have meant `input < '1'`.

Answer (score 0):

- When you do the cast like `(short)input`, it doesn't keep the bit representation but transform it into the new type. A `char c = 255` being casted to a signed 8-bit integer doesn't become a signed integer -1 , but still 255. to keep the bit representation, you can try some ways like `int8_t i = -*(int8_t*)&c;`. also, a `short` is 2 bytes.
- comparing a char for value less than 1 seems weird. '1' should be 49. Maybe check out the [ASCII Table](https://theasciicode.com.ar/).
- The looping might be caused by entering too many inputs, or a newline character. Remember a `%c` consumes only 1 character at one time, including new lines. So, if your input is "-1", it first scans `'-'`, enter the loop again, then scans '1'. Change to `scanf(" %c", input);` to remove any white spaces (space, tab, or `\n`)

Comment: yeah we figured out what was the reason for over printing something like 10 minutes ago and now thinking of using a string maybe. any opinion on using a string. we all so want to use as less memory as possible

Comment: i don't quite understand what do you mean of "Using less memory". But for a direction, you just need to try declare less variables, that should do it.